# How can you locate sprite images in a div that changes height and width according to text inside?

Tags: css

How can you locate the first of the sprite images at the bottom of a div that changes height and width according text inside?  Or is it not possible?

(I tried background-position: right 100% bottom 50%; but it did not work for dynamic div size.)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't possible.

You'd be best off creating a single image and background-positioning that to the bottom-right.